# The scope of the window object stops work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the public folder is the config.js script, which I import into index.html.

In this config.js, I create global variables:

```
window.globalConfig = {
  VERSION: "v1.0",
};
```

Then, in App.tsx I try to access them:

```
console.log (
    "global config =" + JSON.stringify ((window as any) .globalConfig)
  );
```

For localhost route: 3000 / - this works

[image: screenshot console output localhost:3000/]

For routes with two slashes (e.g. localhost: 3000 / page / page1) - this does not work

[image: screenshot console output localhost:3000/page/page1]

Comment: And that uncaught syntax error there, that's nothing to worry about, right?

Comment: i dont think so global value = undefined

Comment: @johnrokfeller If JavaScript crashes before reaching `window.globalConfig = {VERSION: "v1.0"};` then the code is never executed. I suggest solving the syntax error first, then check if this problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in App.tsx:

```
import React from "react";

interface GlobalConfig {
  VERSION: string;
}

declare global {
  interface Window {
    globalConfig: GlobalConfig;
  }
}

function App() {
  console.log("Version:", window.globalConfig.VERSION);
  return (...); // Your code.
}

export default App;
```